# Failover Cluster Manager - Location of the stored clusters

Tags: sql-server, cluster, windows-cluster

I have about a dozen clusters that i monitor daily.  I use the Failover Cluster Manager under MMC for a dashboard view of the clusters.

Two things i am looking for.

1. Where are the cluster names that populate the left panel of the application stored?
   [image]
2. *longshot*  Is there a way to display the value of the Name field that is in the Cluster properties General tab on the primary middle panel?

Comment: Is your question where is MMC storing the names of clusters you've connected to before? Also, given that you've tagged sql-server, do you find yourself caring about the actual Windows cluster day to day or the functionality that it provides (either a failover cluster instance or Availability Group)?

Comment: Ben -  yes, where are the names of the clusters stored at from previous usage.

Comment: I think it's going to be somewhere in the `C:\Users\«username»\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\MMC` file. But looking at mine, I don't see it in a human-readable form. What are you actually trying to do? That is, once you have that list of names, then what?

Comment: Ben - so i can copy the information into a central area and read from it

Comment: Are you set on using MMC? Or would using the FailoverClusters powershell module (which can readily get into a portable format) work for you?

Comment: Ben - I would really like to continue using the MMC, but i am open to the powershell idea.   do you have a script that can replicate the contents of the MMS screen (my powershell skills are limited)

Comment: I don't. Nor do I think I'd want one script that would do everything that the MMC does. But I would encourage you to try it anyways. Install the FailoverClusters module and start tooling around. Here's a start - `Get-Cluster -Name yourCluster | Get-ClusterGroup` will show you roles on the cluster. From there, you're only limited by your imagination. And, if you run into problems, I think you know a good place to go for questions. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Cluster names are stored in Active Directory, similar to how computer and server names are registered in AD.

Comment: i use the failover cluster manager from different systems to monitor the same clusters.    if i add a new cluster into the FCM application, and come back tomorrow, the new cluster is displayed.   but on different systems, the newly added cluster is not displayed.  so my thoughts are that the information is stored locally on the machine running the FCM application.